# XSL unescape HTML inside CDATA

Tags: xml, xslt, cdata, html-escape-characters

I'm trying to transform XML:

```
 <catalog>
            <country><![CDATA[ WIN8 &lt;b&gt;X&lt;/b&gt; Mac OS ]]></country>
    </catalog>
```

into

```
<catalog>
        <country><![CDATA[  WIN8 <b>X</b> Mac OS ]]></country>        
</catalog>
```

with an XSL transform.

I know that using disable-output-escaping="yes" or cdata-section-elements I could transform escaped characters into unescaped and put inside CDATA, but this does not work if charaters are already inside CDATA.

Is there a simple way for this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
<catalog>
  <country><![CDATA[  WIN8 <b>X</b> Mac OS ]]></country>        
</catalog>
```

is equivalent to

```
<catalog>
  <country> WIN8 &lt;b&gt;X&lt;/b&gt; Mac OS </country>
</catalog>
```

Which is exactly what you get when using

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="country/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

The point is that `disable-output-escaping` (DOE) has no effect in an element that falls into `cdata-section-elements` (CSE). That's because both directives disable output escaping.

The text value `" WIN8 <b>X</b> Mac OS "` becomes:

- when serialized normally: `WIN8 &lt;b&gt;X&lt;/b&gt; Mac OS`
- when serialized with CSE: `<![CDATA[ WIN8 <b>X</b> Mac OS ]]>`
- when serialized with DOE: `WIN8 <b>X</b> Mac OS`

Note how the last two renderings are exactly the same, except for the enclosing `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>`.

CDATA disables output escaping for text node children of an element and *in exchange* encloses them in `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` markers to make up for the lost level of escaping.

If you additionally set DOE on an `<xsl:value-of>` that outputs a text into an element that has CSE set, nothing happens. Output escaping *already is* disabled.

Therefore this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:output cdata-section-elements="country" />

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="country/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will give you exactly what your input was.

That's why you cannot get rid of double escaping and have `CDATA` *during the same transformation*. You could use a two-step approach (1st step disables output escaping, 2nd step adds back CDATA) if you positively must have CDATA in the result document — but personally I think it's not worth it.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but what I want to transform is a text inside CDATA that is already escaped. <country><![CDATA[ WIN8 &lt;b&gt;X&lt;/b&gt; Mac OS ]]></country>
into : <country><![CDATA[  WIN8 <b>X</b> Mac OS ]]></country> 
I want to keep the CDATA and transform only the entities.
I know that this is not as an xml should look like, but this is my situation.

Comment: Forget CDATA. You don't need it. CDATA is nothing but a parsing hint that has no bearing on the data it encloses. In the in-memory representation of an XML document it does not even exist. I recommend you use the natively escaped version and get on with things that matter.

Comment: @andreyro I've added a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This is another solution, use CDATA inside an xsl:text with disable-output-escaping="yes":

```
<xsl:template match="/" >
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[
    <script>
    var thisTextIsNotEscaped = "<b>this text is normally escaped, but not in this case</b>";
    </script>
    ]]>
</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```