# XSLT output to HTML from XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML that looks like this.

```
<item>
<title>Fastfood</title>
<description><![CDATA[<p>
<b> For more info, visit us </b><a href ="www.website.com">www.website.com</a></p>
  ]]></description>
  <link>http://www.website.com/</link>
  <author>TCPC</author>
  <guid  isPermaLink="false">a57c770b-a85d-437f-aceb-fd0fc3a0bfb2</guid>
  <pubDate>Mon, 25 Nov 2013 15:39:48 GMT</pubDate>
  <enclosure url="http://www.website.com/images/logo.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="16645" />
  </item>
```

With a XSLT that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
  <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 10"> <!--Displays only 10 entries-->

      <div style="background-color:#a61f2e;color:white;padding:4px; padding-left:1em;">
        <span style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 1.5em;">
          <a id ="{author}"></a>
          <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em; margin-right:1em;">
        <br></br>
        <h6 style="font-style:italic">
          <xsl:value-of select="pubDate"/>
        </h6>
        <br></br>
        <span style ="font: normal 14px/1.5 'Segoe UI'">
          <xsl:value-of select="description" />
        </span>
        <br></br>
      </div>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <br></br>
  <hr></hr>
</html>
```

I want my output to be like this:
 **For more info, visit us** www.website.com

```
But I get this:
<b> For more info, visit us </b><a href ="www.website.com">www.website.com</a></p>
```

Comment: You could add `disable-output-escaping="yes"` to your `<xsl:value-of>` element. That said, putting a `<p>` element inside of a `<span>` does not look like a good idea, you probably should use a `<div>` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489560/xsl-unescape-html-inside-cdata

Comment: I have no control of the XML file. Thanks that worked

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
<span style ="font: normal 14px/1.5 'Segoe UI'">
    <xsl:value-of select="description" />
</span>>
```

To

```
<div style ="font: normal 14px/1.5 'Segoe UI'"> 
  <xsl:value-of select="description/p/b" />
  <a href="{description/p/a/@href}" >
     <xsl:value-of select="description/p/a" />
  </a>
</div>
```